# Got an error whlie fetching vimeo videos using vimeo php librafy

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

When I tried to use vimeo php api I got error.
I am not familiar with php so please help me.

`C:\gonode\php>php vif.php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "Vimeo\CURLOPT_HEADER" in C:\gon
ode\php\vendor\vimeo\vimeo-api\src\Vimeo\Vimeo.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 C:\gonode\php\vif.php(11): Vimeo\Vimeo->__construct('41330335c8dbeea...', 'qE
mqv5/oGdByG2Z...')
#1 {main}
thrown in C:\gonode\php\vendor\vimeo\vimeo-api\src\Vimeo\Vimeo.php on line 72`

This is my php code :

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Include the Composer autoload file

// Replace with your Vimeo API credentials
$clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
$clientSecret = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';
$accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';

// Initialize the Vimeo client
$client = new \Vimeo\Vimeo($clientId, $clientSecret);
$client->setToken($accessToken);

// Define a text file path to write the video information
$textFilePath = 'videos.txt';

try {
    // Fetch all videos from the app
    $response = $client->request('/me/videos', [], 'GET');
    $videos = json_decode($response['body'], true);

    // Create or open a text file to write video information
    $file = fopen($textFilePath, 'w');

    // Loop through the videos and write their URLs to the text file
    foreach ($videos['data'] as $video) {
        $videoTitle = $video['name'];
        $videoURL = $video['link'];
        fwrite($file, "Video Title: $videoTitle\nVideo URL: $videoURL\n\n");
    }

    fclose($file);
    echo "All videos fetched and written to $textFilePath";
} catch (\Vimeo\Exceptions\VimeoRequestException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you haven't activated the cURL extension?